# 'DELETE' Request Not Deleting With Jquery and Express

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm building an api using node/express and jquery and my DELETE requests are not firing for some reason.

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.formula-body').on('click', function (e) {
   if (e.target.className == 'fa-trash-o') {
      $.ajax({
         url: 'formula-api/' + e.target.id,
         type: 'DELETE',
         success: updateIngredient
      });
   }
});

function updateIngredient(data) {
   $('.formula-body').empty();
   var output = '';
   $.each(data, function (key, item) {
      output = `
    <tr>
      <td>${item.name}</td>
      <td>${item.amount}</td>
      <td>${item.notes}</td>
      <td><a><span id ="${key}" class="fa fa-trash-o">  </span></a></td>
    </tr>
    `;
      $('tbody').append(output);
   });
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="centered">
<h2>Your Formula</h2>
  <table class="centered-block pure-table pure-table-striped formula-table">
    <thead class="thead-styled">
      <tr class="centered">
          <th>Ingredient</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Notes</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="formula-body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

This is the routing I'm using with express to handle the DELETE request.

**ROUTES:**

```
var app = require('express');
var router = app.Router();
var formulas = require('../data/formula.json');

router.get('/formula-api', function(req, res){
  res.json(formulas);
});

router.post('/formula-api', function(req, res){
  formulas.push(req.body);
  res.json(formulas);
});

router.delete('/formula-api/:id', function(req, res) {
  formulas.splice(req.params.id, 1);
  formulas.push(req.body);
  res.json(formulas);
});

module.exports = router;
```

The POST and GET requests work just fine, and I'm unable to troubleshoot the issue.  The console brings up no errors.

I've imported the `body-parser` util into `app.js` so that shouldn't be an issue.

The basic idea is that I have a table that has a new row appended to it each time a form is filled out.

The page looks like this:

[image: Example table]

The idea is that I want the trash can to delete the appropriate row whenever it's clicked, but right now it does nothing.

Comment: have you tried to do a `console.log(req.params);` in your route to make sure you are receiving a param?

Comment: @TaylorAckley - thank you for the comment, will check in morning to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured this one out.  My problems were two-fold.

1).  I wasn't actually grabbing the icon when I clicked on it because I need to include both font-awesome selectors in the `$('Grab Element')` statement in jquery.

2).  In my routes section I had a line that states:

```
formulas.push(req.body)
```

Which was shoving my empty object back into my JSON array.

So to rectify these errors I made the following changes:

**CHANGE 1:**

```
if (e.target.className == 'fa-trash-o') {
```

got changed to:

```
if (e.target.className == 'fa fa-trash-o') {
```

I'm not sure why you can't just use one class as a selector.....I'm assuming it's something particular to Font Awesome.  (Would be happy to get corrected if I'm wrong).

**CHANGE 2:**

```
router.delete('/formula-api/:id', function(req, res) {
  formulas.splice(req.params.id, 1);
  formulas.push(req.body);
  res.json(formulas);
});
```

got changed to:

```
router.delete('/formula-api/:id', function(req, res) {
  formulas.splice(req.params.id, 1);
  res.json(formulas);
});
```

This did the trick and everything's copacetic.